# Segmentation fault when using I/O redirection to input a data set

Tags: c

Source:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int load(char fileName[], int array[]);
int sort(int array[], int length);
int print(int length, int array[]);

int main() {

   char fileName[300];
   int numList[300];
   int length;

   printf("File Name: ");
   scanf("%s", fileName);

   length = print(sort(numList,load(fileName, numList)), numList);
   printf("\nLength: %i\n", length);
   printf("Finished execution.\n");

   return 0;
}

int load(char fileName[], int array[]) {

   FILE *input = fopen(fileName, "r");

   int length = 0, i = 0;

   if(input == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error accessing file.\n");
   } else {
      while(fscanf(input, "%i", &array[i]) != EOF) {
         i++;
         length++;
      }
   }

   fclose(input);
   return length;
}

int sort(int array[], int length) {
  int a, b, c;

  for (a = 0 ; a < ( length - 1 ); a++) {
    for (b = 0 ; b < length - a - 1; b++) {
      if (array[b] > array[b+1]) {
        c = array[b];
        array[b] = array[b+1];
        array[b+1] = c;
      }
    }
  }
   return length;
}

int print(int length, int array[]) {
   int i;

   printf("\n[NUMBERS]\n\n");
   for (i = 0; i< length; i++) {
      printf("[N]%i\n", array[i]);
   }
   return length;
}
```

I am required to use I/O redirection to submit a random data set of integers to the program, but when I use redirection to submit the file containing the data set, it throws a segfault. I am very familiar with segfaults and why they are traditionally thrown, but I've been sitting in front of this program for hours now with no progress on identifying where the issue stems from.

Comment: Did you try using the debugger to see where exactly the segfault arises? Also - it appears your code only reads the filename from STDIN, everything else is read directly from a file. You can't redirect explicit reading from a file; you can only redirect the three IO handles that are open for every process.

Comment: You say you are required to use redirection, but that means using stdin/stdout. However, you program is clearly attempting the read data from a file. That doesnt really mesh.

Comment: You `fclose(input)` even when `input == NULL`.

Comment: You should break up this line into two separate lines:              `length = print(sort(numList,load(fileName, numList)), numList);`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some proposed changes, to make your code read from stdin instead of from a named file, which is what you say is needed:

```
        int main() {

           //char fileName[300];
           int numList[300];
           int length;

           //printf("File Name: ");
           //scanf("%s", fileName);

           length = print(sort(numList,load(stdin, numList)), numList);
           printf("\nLength: %i\n", length);
           printf("Finished execution.\n");

           return 0;
        }

        int load(FILE* input, int array[]) {

           //FILE *input = fopen(fileName, "r");

           int length = 0, i = 0;

           if(input == NULL) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Error accessing file.\n");
           } else {
              while(fscanf(input, "%i", &array[i]) != EOF) {
                 i++;
                 length++;
              }
           }

           //fclose(input);
           return length;
        }

        int sort(int array[], int length) {
          int a, b, c;

          for (a = 0 ; a < ( length - 1 ); a++) {
            for (b = 0 ; b < length - a - 1; b++) {
              if (array[b] > array[b+1]) {
                c = array[b];
                array[b] = array[b+1];
                array[b+1] = c;
              }
            }
          }
           return length;
        }
```

You need to update the `load()` proto near to top to:`int load(FILE* input, int array[]);`